# How do I save individual item in a collection with @ngrx DB

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have the following `@ngrx` effect which is triggered when a search is complete. The `SEARCH_COMPLETE` event emits a **collection** of products.

I want to save each product in the collection to the IndexedDB, not the whole collection as a single value. To achieve this, I created a new `Observable` from the products which uses the `@ngrx` DB observable. I laso had to use the `subscribe` call to make it work.

My question is, is this the right way to do it? Or is it a better way without using the `subscribe` method?

```
@Effect()
addProductsToDB$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(ProductsSearchActions.ActionTypes.SEARCH_COMPLETE)
    .map((action: ProductsSearchActions.SearchCompleteAction) => action.payload)
    .switchMap(products => {
        return Observable.from(products as IProduct[])
            .do(product => {
                this.db.insert('products', [{ product }])
                    .subscribe();
            })
            .map(() => new ProductDBActions.ProductAddedSuccessAction(true));
    });
```

Comment: try to do "Observable.from(products as IProduct[]).switchMap(product=> this.db.insert('products', [{ product }])) .map(() => new ProductDBActions.ProductAddedSuccessAction(true));

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it works. I can mark your response as an answer if you can create an answer below. Can I ask you why it works without a ```subscribe``` call?

Comment: @wonderfulworld It works because the `switchMap` involves an implicit `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do

```
 Observable.from(products as IProduct[])
  .switchMap(product=> this.db.insert('products', [{ product }]))
  .map(() => new ProductDBActions.ProductAddedSuccessAction(true));
```